# Text from Preamble in LaTeX document

Tags: preamble

I'm getting an fl in my document when I compile the the following code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[x-1a]{pdfx}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Can any body tell me what's going on?[image]

Comment: I get `pdfTeX warning: pdflatex: dangling objects discarded, no output file produced.`  and no pdf file at all (texlive 2019) can you show the full log from your test file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You not only get a strange character, but also

```latex
! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
(inputenc)                in inputencoding `utf8'.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1398 \ifcat ^^c0
                  \active \pdf@activecharstrue\fi
```

I can only reproduce it by running TeX Live 2016.

You should update your TeX distribution. The bug in `pdfx` was fixed already in 2017.

The problem with `pdfx.sty` in TeX Live 2016 is at line 1398

```
\ifcat ^^c0\active \pdf@activecharstrue\fi
```

which should be

```
\ifnum\catcode`^^c0=\active\pdf@activecharstrue\fi
```

or

```
\ifcat\noexpand^^c0\active \pdf@activecharstrue\fi
```

Unfortunately, there's no other way than to copy `pdfx.sty` in your working directory and make the fix in the copy.

Of course, using an up-to-date TeX distribution is much better.

Comment: I did notice that... It's weird because the actual file where it showed up was a file which uses a lot of \include{other file} and the errors didn't show up there. At any rate, I'm updating my TeX (my interface is up-to-date but apparently TeX isn't). Assuming the error goes away, I'll give you the check tomorrow once I download everything. Thanks for your help.